# mount s3 bucket using RClone on windows

Tags: amazon-s3, rclone

I use RClone to mount s3 bucket as a local disk, the local disk disappears after i close the CMD.

how to keep the drive accessible after i close the cmd, or is their a replacement for RClone

Comment: Is the windows instance local or is it an EC2 instance?

Comment: EC2 instance, and if it works in local machine that would be great too

Comment: Take a look at Storage Gateway. This worked for me like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The bucket-based remotes (e.g. Swift, S3, Google Compute Storage, B2, Hubic) do not support the concept of empty directories, so empty directories will have a tendency to disappear once they fall out of the directory cache.